# Placing a bar/graphic before the section headers

Tags: sectioning, memoir, titlesec

I've used the titlesec package to produce section headers like this:

[image: screenshot]

<sup>Click for a full-resolution version.</sup>

Using this minimal code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\newcommand\secbar {
    \tikz[baseline, trim left=3.2cm] 
    {
        \fill [white] (3cm,0.1ex) rectangle +(0.2cm,1.1ex);
        \draw [gray!95, fill=gray!80] (0cm,0.1ex) rectangle (3cm,1.1ex);        
    }
}
\newcommand\subsecbar {
    \tikz[baseline, trim left=2.2cm] 
    {
        \fill [white] (2cm,0.1ex) rectangle +(0.2cm,1.1ex);
        \fill [blue!40] (0cm,0.1ex) rectangle (2cm,1.1ex);      
    }

\titleformat{\section}{\large}{}{0cm}{\secbar}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\large}{}{0cm}{\subsecbar}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\end{document}
```

However, I'd like the use the memoir package, which is incompatible with titlesec. I know that memoir has its own commands to alter sections. For example, `\setsechook{Hello}` will place "Hello" before the section header. However, it also places a newline after "Hello". I haven't made able to make much progress looking at the memoir documentation.

Can someone guide me to reproducing the same section header commands as above but using the memoir package and without titlesec?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possibility:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\newcommand\secbar{%
    \tikz[baseline, trim left=3.2cm] 
    {
        \fill [white] (3cm,0.1ex) rectangle +(0.2cm,1.1ex);
        \draw [gray!95, fill=gray!80] (0cm,0.1ex) rectangle (3cm,1.1ex);        
    }%
}
\newcommand\subsecbar{%
    \tikz[baseline, trim left=2.2cm] 
    {
        \fill [white] (2cm,0.1ex) rectangle +(0.2cm,1.1ex);
        \fill [blue!40] (0cm,0.1ex) rectangle (2cm,1.1ex);      
    }%
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{%
  \sechook%
  \@startsection{section}{1}%  level 1
      {\secindent}%            heading indent
      {\beforesecskip}%        skip before the heading
      {\aftersecskip}%         skip after the heading
      {\noindent\llap{\secbar}\normalfont\secheadstyle}} % font
\setsecheadstyle{\large\memRTLraggedright}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{%
  \subsechook%
  \@startsection{subsection}{2}%  level 2
      {\subsecindent}%            heading indent
      {\beforesubsecskip}%        skip before the heading
      {\aftersubsecskip}%         skip after the heading
      {\noindent\llap{\subsecbar}\normalfont\subsecheadstyle}} % font
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\memRTLraggedright}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, you don't really need TikZ to draw the colored bars:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\newcommand\MyBar[5]{%
  {\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\color{#1}\fbox{\color{#2}\rule{#3}{#4}}}\hspace{#5}}

\newcommand\secbar{\MyBar{gray!95}{gray!80}{2.8cm}{1ex}{0.2cm}}
\newcommand\subsecbar{\MyBar{blue!40}{blue!40}{1.8cm}{1ex}{0.2cm}}%

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{%
  \sechook%
  \@startsection{section}{1}%  level 1
      {\secindent}%            heading indent
      {\beforesecskip}%        skip before the heading
      {\aftersecskip}%         skip after the heading
      {\noindent\llap{\secbar}\normalfont\secheadstyle}} % font
\setsecheadstyle{\large\memRTLraggedright}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{%
  \subsechook%
  \@startsection{subsection}{2}%  level 2
      {\subsecindent}%            heading indent
      {\beforesubsecskip}%        skip before the heading
      {\aftersubsecskip}%         skip after the heading
      {\noindent\llap{\subsecbar}\normalfont\subsecheadstyle}} % font
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\memRTLraggedright}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very in-depth answer. I've chosen this as the right answer.

Answer (score 5):

Why all that recoding? Just adding `\leavevmode\llap{\secbar}` to `\setsecheadstyle` seems to work fine.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\newcommand\MyBar[5]{%
{\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\color{#1}\fbox{\color{#2}\rule{#3}{#4}}}\hspace{#5}}

\newcommand\secbar{\MyBar{gray!95}{gray!80}{2.8cm}{1ex}{0.2cm}}
\newcommand\subsecbar{\MyBar{blue!40}{blue!40}{1.8cm}{1ex}{0.2cm}}%


\setsecheadstyle{\large\memRTLraggedright\leavevmode\llap{\secbar}}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\memRTLraggedright\leavevmode\llap{\subsecbar}}




\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I had no idea it could be done so simply. Thank you!